# Facebook error: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: access_token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the C# Facebook library. With that i wanted to post something on my own wall, but i'm getting an error (as described in the title):

> (OAuthException) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not
>   exist: access_token=438781769472xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This is what i'm doing in code:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(myAccessToken);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = "Test message";
args["caption"] = "Caption";
args["description"] = "Description";
args["name"] = "Name";
args["picture"] = "";
args["link"] = "";

// Not sure which one to use, but both give same error
facebookClient.Post(appAccessToken+"/feed", args);
//facebookClient.Post(appAccessToken, args);
```

Anyone any idea what the problem might be and how i can solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the appAccessToken parameter to the Post method parameter. Your post URL will be automatically appended with the myAccessToken value used when instantiating facebookClient. If you amend your call to be `facebookClient.Post("/feed", args);` it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
 facebookClient.Post(appAccessToken+"/feed", args);
```

should change to

```
  facebookClient.Post("<page_id>/feed", args);
```

You need add the page id to which you need to post